# When I share a url with Chrome using a Intent, The "chooser" is displayed many times

Tags: android, google-chrome

my code:

```
String youtube = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rk6_hdRtJOE";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(youtube));
startActivity(intent);
```

The strange thing is that only happens with Chrome. I don't have the problem if I use Opera or Firefox.

Does anyone know what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Chrome isn't the default browser, it will show the chooser again when the site redirects to the mobile version. You can avoid this by changing the URL.

```
String youtube = "https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Rk6_hdRtJOE";
```

Comment: Thanks! Very simple solution.